# How to call a function associated with a dropdown by firing change event on it

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function on a change of a dropdown and change event will be fired with jquery........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function a(a) {


            alert('Funtion A');
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sel').change(function(){
                a('a')
            })


            $('button').click(function(){
                $('#sel').click()
                $('#sel').val('B');

            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="sel" >
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>

    <button type="button">Change</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to set the value of a `<select>` and [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) its `change` event?  That would simply be this:

```
$('#sel').val('B').trigger('change');
```

Or, if you prefer to keep it on two lines as in your current attempt:

```
$('#sel').val('B');
$('#sel').trigger('change');
```

The former is *generally* preferred and consumes slightly less resources, but if you personally prefer two explicit statements as you learn then there's no real harm in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

use the following way to fire  events of on other element

```
$("#sel").trigger("change");
```